# Caught SIGTERM signal when specifying commands in Docker Compose MariaDB image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm running docker with casaOS.

The issue is that specifying variables in 'command' section of docker compose mariaDB *.yml file, such as '--max_allowed_packet=1024' or '--log_warnings=9' raises an error, that such command was not found.

Here is the docker compose file that I'm creating:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb:latest
    command: --max_allowed_packet=1024 --log_warnings=9
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=X
    volumes:
      - /media/user/x/x/config:/config
      - /media/user/x/x/confd:/etc/conf.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And here is part of log which contains information about the error

```
mariadb  | [ls.io-init] done.
mariadb  | /run/s6/basedir/scripts/rc.init: line 76: --max_allowed_packet=2137: not found**
mariadb  | Caught SIGTERM signal!
mariadb  | [migrations] started
mariadb  | [migrations] no migrations found
mariadb  | usermod: no changes
```

I've also tried to download MariaDB image from casaOS inbuilt market, and specifying these commands in the GUI 'Container Command' section - It raises the same error.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with solving this issue or at least point out the issue, since I'm not really sure what it could be. My only guess is that it could be that casaOS affects installation of docker images and 'breaks' command section of an image. I could not find any topic on this issue, and from what it seems, specifying commands in *yml file works for other people creating MariaDB docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Docker Official Image of MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) accepts MariaDB command line options on the entrypoint's command.

The [LinuxServer](https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-mariadb/#bootstrapping-a-new-instance) image you are using requires the configuration be placed in a configuration file.